# What should i use to secure parameters in a REST webservice

Tags: android, web-services, security, rest, jersey

i want to develop an authentication web service, which can be used in an android app to login and have access to other services. So basicaly i'm sending credentials over HTTP requests and granting access to the user if everything is good. I need to secure those credentials so they cannot be intercepted by an unwanted user.

I'm using eclipse with Tomcat 7, Jersey for my rest webservices, spring and hibernate.
My webservice goes something like this

```
@GET
@Path("/login/{id}/{pass}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String login(@PathParam("id") int id,@PathParam("pass") String pass) {
    String res="Null parameters";

    if(id!=0 && !pass.isEmpty())
    {
        try {
            User user = service.getOne(id);
            if(user.getPass().equals(pass))
                res="Success";
            else
                res="Fail";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            res="User not found";
        }
    }
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Result" + "</title>"
    + "<body><h1>" + res + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
}
```

I'm using it to test with the browser, i didn't start coding the client yet.

I'm really scratching my head here, i've been looking around the web, some are talking about OAuth 2.0 and others about HMAC, and i don't know which one to use, and if there is another methode please let me know.

If you know a helpful tutorial about how to implement security to my project it would be great, any other suggestions are welcome. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the level of security you need, for your application.

There are a lot of complicated security systems, but for most applications these are quite overkill.

If you're simply looking for some basic protection of passwords, without dealing with payments or really sensitive data you could do the following simple things.

1. If you can, move your service to work through https. All data will get automatically protected by that already.
2. Hash the password. A lot of languages have build-in support already for simple hashing such as MD5 and SHA1, if not you can google their implementation, they are often used. 
   This means that not even you as admin know the real password. You simply save the hashed pass in your database, and compare hashes.
3. In your client-side, add a salt to your hashing. Probably if you google step 2, this will already be in there but otherwise it simply means that you do something like hash("132rjfASDF!"+password"+vnsadfr1!Z");  to make it even more random.

These simple steps can be achieved pretty easily and fast, and will provide your service all the security it needs most of the times. 
If you're really dealing with things such as payments and sensitive data, you should look into more serious solutions.

ps. Don't think that using 'post' instead of 'get' is any kind of security and it really doesn't matter which you use for this, from an Android point of view. People will have to use a program to fetch network connections anyway to see the link come by (per example WireShark) and in that reading GET parameters is just as easy as reading POST parameters.

Comment: I think hashing is enough for my application, i don't need an FBI like protection, it's about office order (mail services). I will look that up. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, like i said most of the times that's good enough. There are a lot of copy-paste solutions on the internet for Android/Java md5/sha1 hash. good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair bit of confusion in some of the above answers, and indeed the question itself.  Some notes:

- First off, REST is meant to be stateless.  As such you should not have a 'login' function that sets some sort of server-side flag but instead should pass credentials with each and every request
- Handling the credentials should be done in Jersey in a filter rather than in the individual resource methods.  There are various examples on Stack Overflow that show this
- If you are storing passwords on your server then use BCrypt to hash them.  Bcrypt allows you to dial up the time taken to calculate a hash, so gives some measure of future-proofing against Moore's law
- You should use HTTPS for all communications.  It gives you another layer of security and protection for cheap (programming-effort-wise, anyway)
- If you want to protect the information in your request against tampering then you should look at something like [Hawk](http://github.com/hueniverse/hawk).  This gives you the ability to protect your request headers and body against tampering, and can also work as an authentication mechanism as well

There is a lot more to securing your REST endpoints properly, but if you follow the above you'll have hit the major points.

Answer (score 0):

usually username and password are sent thorough post request which hides it from user.. which is good incase some one standing over your shoulder and if they could see the url then they could see your username and password... other than that use SSL on server side..

Comment: Yes i know that the GET methode is not the right one, POST is better since it hides the parameters. but i need to send these parameters crypted, is SSL enough ?